# Warnings when running turtlebot_gazebo

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Environment

- Ubuntu 12.04.2 (run on Virtualbox on Mac OSX Mavericks)
- hydro

### Questions

I installed turtlebot-simulator.

- `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot-simulator`
- `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot-apps`
- `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-tutlebot-rviz-launchers`

Run `roscore` and launched the simulator.
`roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch`

I got these warning.

- `OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU`
- `OpenGL Warning: You called glBindTexture with a target of 0x806f, but the texture you wanted was target 0xde1 [1D: de0 2D: de1 3D: 806f cube: 8513]`

**Are these warnings serious? If so, how can I fix them?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194797/warnings-when-running-turtlebot_gazebo/) by [wkentaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20444/wkentaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2014-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running OpenGL applications inside VMs is often fraught with problems. If things are generally working it's likely ok to ignore them. Otherwise you may need to look into updating your video drivers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1